# Angular: Relative js/css path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm new in angular, bower, grunt, etc stuff so I completely stuck with current issue.
My project is built based on angular.
In my index.html path to js/css like this

```
<script src="/scripts/shared/flow-item.js"></script>
```

after compiling with grunt path to js/css in index.html

```
<script src="scripts/app.da1aee60.js">
```

so that if i deploy project in ROOT on tomcat everything works perfect
but if i deploy it in some folder like MyProject/ and call index.html we see  application still looks for scripts by path http://localhost:8080/scripts/app.da1aee60.js instead http://localhost:8080/MyProject/scripts/app.da1aee60.js
Is it possible in some say project look for script in proper path?

Comment: Use a yeoman generator like this: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

Answer (score 0):

You can set base path in html (inside head tag):

```
<base href="/scripts/MyProject/" />
```

Comment: no, the idea path to script should be localhost:8080/MyProject/scripts if I deploy project in folder MyProject and changing href to MyProject/script doesnt work if you use node to test project or if you deploy it on ROOT. I think I should add  deploy folder dynamically in some way